# When setting up PHP mailer who should I set the From address as to avoid spam/blacklisting?

Tags: php, html, email

I'm using PHP mailer to as part of an enquiry form that I'm building for a client. One thing I've noticed in testing is that when I use my yahoo account as the FROM and my gmail as the to it works fine for a while but then it starts rejecting, I'm assuming because gmail is smart enough to know that the email isn't actually coming from Yahoo.

What is the best solution to this? I could use the email from the person who has actually filled in the form to show as the FROM address but I'm worried that this may eventually cause the same problem anyway? I could also send it from an email on the domain that its sending from but will that stop it from appearing as spam or black listing that email?

Any help or guidance would be great?

Comment: You should set it from the email you want them to reply to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not Yahoo -- don't pretend to be them! Set the `From` field to an address at the domain that's sending the mail (e.g, if your domain was `example.com`, send from something like `inquiries@example.com` or `noreply@example.com`).

Comment: So as long as its an email thats from my domain it should come through fine, even for large volumes of emails? Just a note the only reason I used email was because I was worried my own email that I was testing with my be blacklisted or something.

Comment: Generally, yes. If you send a *very* high volume of mail, you may run into some issues, but you'll probably just fill up your Gmail inbox first. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting tagged as a spammer because you are sending the same message over and over. Set up your own mail server without a spam filter while developing if this is a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so when I go live with this form its unlikely they will get more than 1-2 enquiries a day...are you saying that if the volume of emails is this low its unlikely to cause a problem?

Comment: By your description of the symptoms, the first few messages were okay, so if your volume is modest, you should be okay when you go live. But many things could go wrong ...

Comment: Yes I know what you mean, so many things can go wrong! I'm just trying to understand what the thresholds are with regards to sending out emails using something like PHP mailer and if there are ways round it.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to [SPF records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPF_record). `mail()` will most likely try and send the mail directly to the server(s) identified by the [MX record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) of the recipient domain, and because you are not sending from an IP address that is recognised as one of Yahoo's, Google will reject the email. If you are on *nix, you may be able to configure your system's `sendmail` program to relay via Yahoo. This is not an option on Windows (I don't think) because Windows has no `sendmail` and PHP will send the mail itself.

If you want a cross-platform solution you can use something like [PEAR::Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) to relay the message through Yahoo's SMTP servers - this should resolve the problem as long as the SPF record is the source of the problem.

If your email is getting flagged as spam because of the content of the message, the only solution is to change the content of the message.